# Python xarray.DataArray: resize coordinates

Tags: python, python-xarray

For my Python package [numericalmodel](https://github.com/nobodyinperson/python3-numericalmodel) that is supposed to help prototyping simple numerical models I wrote classes for self-describing datasets. I recently stumbled upon the awesome [xarray library](https://github.com/pydata/xarray) and am now considering to use `xarray.Dataset` and `xarray.DataArray` instead of my own classes for data management.

I searched the [xarray documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/index.html) but didn't find an answer to my question. Sorry if I overlooked something.

As far as I understand `xarray`, its structures are best used for *static* data that doesn't change its shape. But for my `numericalmodel` package I need to constantly expand arrays with new timely values, namely at each new time step. I don't know the points in time in advance because the time step lengths may be determined adaptively for each equation that is solved.

So my question:

### How does one **expand** an `xarray.DataArray`'s coordinate?

This might boil down to „How to expand an `xarray.DataArray`” in general

A possible method of doing this should:

- not have too much *overhead* (e.g. not rely on creating new `DataArray`s, then reassigning coordinates, then deleting the old one)
- possibly handle other data variables that depend on that coordinate

My guess is that it's not possible just like this. Normally, if you don't find anything on a question you have, it either means that the answer is bluntly obvious or it's very nontrivial ;-)

Thanks!

nobodyinperson

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that this isn't possible to do efficiently with xarray's current data model (built on numpy arrays). Xarray doesn't support append, because append in numpy entails a complete copy.

See this recent mailing list discussion for details, but basically the currently recommended approach is to accumulate results in a list and call `concat` only once, at the end: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/xarray/BAN7WobAfyw

That said, there are ways this could be done efficiently (with appends along one dimension in amortized constant time) if we built an alternative storage layer to use instead of numpy arrays. Xarray actually has a few of these already, so this is not as hard as it might seem. Anyways, if you're interested in potentially working on this, I am happy to discuss what next steps would look like in a GitHub issue.