Add some values to one existing coordinate in Array Dataarray
Let's say we open one NetCDF file and get a DataArray  da like
<xarray.DataArray (x: 2, y: 3)>
array([[0.50793919, 0.49505336, 0.19573345],
       [0.7830897 , 0.82954952, 0.19427877]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1
  * y        (y) int64 0 1 2

Now, our target DataArray da_new looks like
<xarray.DataArray (x: 4, y: 3)>
array([[0.50793919, 0.49505336, 0.19573345],
       [0.7830897 , 0.82954952, 0.19427877],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1 2 3
  * y        (y) int64 0 1 2

To reach our target, we can construct one new DataArray and refill it using the da data, something like
da_new = xr.DataArray(
    data = np.full([4,3], fill_value=np.nan),
    dims = ['x','y'],
    coords=dict(
        x = range(4),
        y = range(3)
    )
)
da_new.loc[0:1,:] = da

However, in my side, this method is a little bit tiring, especially when there are many dimensions of the DataArray.
So, I'm wondering is there any simple and explicit method to do this.
Many thanks.

Can you edit the question to show explicitly what output you would like to get?  Otherwise your brief explanation is not clear enough.  Sometimes it also helps to show something you tried that isn't quite right, and explain how that falls short of what you want.

Not sure there is a good way to enlarge a DataArray.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43733255/16327476

Maybe da.reindex can solve this.

The sequence of steps is sound (create new placeholder array, then copy data into it), but we can use the dimensions from the original so we do not have to hard code dimensions and coordinates for the new array if they are the same as the original.
Make some data
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# Toy data.
ar = np.array([
    [0.50793919, 0.49505336, 0.19573345],
    [0.7830897 , 0.82954952, 0.19427877]])
da = xr.DataArray(
    data = ar,
    dims = ['x','y'],
    coords=dict(
        x = range(2),
        y = range(3)
    ))
da
# array([[0.50793919, 0.49505336, 0.19573345],
#       [0.7830897 , 0.82954952, 0.19427877]])
# Coordinates:
#    x   (x) int64 0 1
#    y   (y) int64 0 1 2

Make bigger placeholder array
# Map some dimensions to new coordinates of any length.
new_coords = dict(x=range(4))

# Make empty placeholder array, replacing some coordinates with new ones.
da_bigger = xr.DataArray(
    dims=da.dims,
    coords=dict(da.coords, **new_coords))

da_bigger

# array([[nan, nan, nan],
#        [nan, nan, nan],
#        [nan, nan, nan],
#        [nan, nan, nan]])
# Coordinates:
#    x  (x) int64 0 1 2 3
#    y  (y) int64 0 1 2

Copy data
# Copy data from original into corresponding coordinates of bigger array.
da_bigger.loc[{k: da[k] for k in new_coords}] = da

da_bigger

# array([[0.50793919, 0.49505336, 0.19573345],
#        [0.7830897 , 0.82954952, 0.19427877],
#        [       nan,        nan,        nan],
#        [       nan,        nan,        nan]])
# Coordinates:
#     x   (x) int64 0 1 2 3
#     y   (y) int64 0 1 2

Assumption: The new coordinates are a superset of the original.
EDIT: Use xr.align
We can get xr.align to do the heavy lifting for the copy operation.  In this example the empty placeholder array is passed directly into align without storing it in a named variable.
da_big2, _ = xr.align(
    da,
    xr.DataArray(
        dims=da.dims,
        coords=dict(da.coords, **new_coords)),
    join="outer")
da_big2
# array([[0.50793919, 0.49505336, 0.19573345],
#        [0.7830897 , 0.82954952, 0.19427877],
#        [       nan,        nan,        nan],
#        [       nan,        nan,        nan]])
# Coordinates:
#     x   (x) int64 0 1 2 3
#     y   (y) int64 0 1 2


Thanks!! This is what I want exactly.

Instead of creating a big, empty placeholder array, we can create a small empty placeholder array with just the new coordinates, and only the dimensions that are changing.  Then xr.align() will copy the original data into an array with the expanded dimensions.
If our original data array da looks like this, with dimensions x and y:
da
# array([[0.50793919, 0.49505336, 0.19573345],
#       [0.7830897 , 0.82954952, 0.19427877]])
# Coordinates:
#    x   (x) int64 0 1
#    y   (y) int64 0 1 2

We can enlarge one or both dimensions using a dict that maps dimension names to new coordinate values that we want to add to the original coordinates.  xr.align() here will return two aligned DataArray objects, one of which has the original data--we keep that one and ignore the second one, which is full of nan.
# Map some dimensions to coordinates to be added.
new_coords2 = dict(x=[2, 3])

# Align original data with new, expanded coordinates.
xr.align(
    da,
    xr.DataArray(dims=new_coords2, coords=new_coords2),
    join="outer")[0]

# array([[0.50793919, 0.49505336, 0.19573345],
#        [0.7830897 , 0.82954952, 0.19427877],
#        [       nan,        nan,        nan],
#        [       nan,        nan,        nan]])
# Coordinates:
#     x   (x) int64 0 1 2 3
#     y   (y) int64 0 1 2

